# Map keyboard key to mouse click in a certain position

Tags: keyboard, mouse, keybindings, mapping

I want to map my keyboard's arrow buttons to mouse left clicks (mouse down/up) at specific areas of my screen.

For example:

- left arrow key   *---(map to)-->* mouse left click at position W: 120px | H: 300px
- right arrow key *---(map to)-->* mouse left click at position W: 120px | H: 300px

Is that possible?

Comment: Though not exact, it's a possible duplicate of [I have a two mouses: one for each hand. How can I set the primary mouse button separately for each mouse?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287609/i-have-a-two-mouses-one-for-each-hand-how-can-i-set-the-primary-mouse-button-s).  Both questions and it's answer is about remapping mouse button(s) to some custom action.

Comment: This question here is about remapping keys, the other about remapping mouse buttons. While there may be common answers for both there may also be answers which only cover one (so no duplicate as such).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globally move mouse pointer and click using VIM keystrokes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139065/globally-move-mouse-pointer-and-click-using-vim-keystrokes)

Comment: @patrix I should have used the phrase "...remapping mouse buttons/keyboard keys to some custom action."   The answer in the link addresses that.

Comment: @allan I'm aware of that. But there are may be solution to the problem posted here which will not fit the question asked in the linked (two mouses) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) together with a custom macro.

[image: keyboard maestro]